# Postman: Newman collection runner unable to send form url-encoded parameters in body with calls

Tags: postman

In postman to send credentials to setup login in the body section x-www-form-ulrencoded. This works absolutely fine.

After exporting this script in newman collection runner, this does not work.

Following is the output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
401 3361ms Login Call [POST] https://<url>/login
------------------------------------------------------------
Request headers:
{
 "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 "host": "<url>",
 "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
 "content-length": 0
}
Request data:
{
  "userid": "user",
  "password": "pswd"
}
------------------------------------------------------------
Response headers:
{
 "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
 "content-type": "application/json",
 "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
 "date": "...",
 "cache-control": "no-cache",
 "content-length": "120",
 "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
 "connection": "close",
 "accept-ranges": "bytes"
}
Response body:
{"errorCode":"401","errorMessage":"Login failed, please check the credentials","errorDescription":"API Request Failure"}
```

Also, when i generate curl code from postman i don't see the user/pswd headers attached:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://<url>/login \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: 5b04e538-498c-9e43-2be9-8523073260f9'
```

Using Postman Chrome app:

```
Postman for Chrome
Version 5.0.2
win / x86-64
Chrome 59.0.3071.115
```

Comment: What I found is that Newman removes the parameters from the url encoded body before sending across to the server. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue over here is the version of Newman installed.
So I got the latest version:

```
//to install
npm install -g newman

//needed to use Newman.run instead of Newman.execute
newman run c:\s -e c:\env --reporters cli,json --reporter-json-export c:\out.json -k

//-k was required to bypass ssl security issues.
```